# Changing UISwitch to On

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch object in my .xib file. Its state is On by default. If the user switches it to Off, I want to ask if he's sure, and if he clicks No - automatically switch it back to On.

So I set these outlet and action in my .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *campaignSwitch;
- (IBAction)checkCampaignSwitch:(id)sender;
```

This is the checkCampaignSwitch method:

```
- (IBAction)checkCampaignSwitch:(id)sender {
    if(self.campaignSwitch.isOn==FALSE)
    {
        [self allertMessage:@"Receive updates" :@"Are you sure you don't want
           to receive updates?" :@"No" :@"Yes"];
    }
}
```

This calls for method to display an Alert message with various parameters (title, text, cancel button and other button).

I also registered for UIAlertViewDelegate and in my .m file I'm trying to implement the clickedButtonAtIndex method like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self.campaignSwitch setOn:TRUE];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the Alert message, but nothing happens when I click the No button. Nor the Yes.
So how do I switch it back On?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to make sure the UIAlertView is delegated:

```
UIAlertView *displayMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc]
   initWithTitle:messageTitle
   message:alertMessage
   **delegate:self**
   cancelButtonTitle:cancelButton
   otherButtonTitles:otherButton,
nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all connections connected in Interface Builder.  Also, make sure your switch statement in your alert view is associated with the right button (i.e. make sure you getting to case 0).

To turn a switch off, see the code below.

```
// Set the switch on
[_switch setOn:YES];

// Set the switch off
[_switch SetOn:NO];
```

Comment: Ahmmm... I think they're connected... How exactly do I make sure of it? And yes, I'm using the code you gave in the clickedButtonAtIndex method, but it just doesn't work, doesn't switch back to On.

Comment: Actually YES and NO and TRUE and FALSE do the same thing, it's probably that you haven't connected your action and your switch in your .xib file with your controller. Rick click on the switch and make sure its outlets are set up.

Comment: I found my mistake - I didn't delegate the UIAlertView. Once I set it to delegate:self - everything worked just fine! Thank you both very much! Appreciate it!

Comment: @8vius yes YES and NO and TRUE and FALSE are the same, I think it makes it more readable especially in this situation

Comment: @Igal you should write your solution up as an answer and accept it

Comment: I wrote it, but for some reason it says I can only accept it in 2 days... Have to wait, I guess...

Comment: @Igal that's the required time before you may except your own answers, you can accept it anytime after that

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this in order for it to be drawn immediately:

```
    [emailAlertSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
```

OR

```
    [emailAlertSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

Is it entering the alertView delegate callback?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `setOn: animated:` method

```
[self.campaignSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

Simply using setOn without animated will not show an animation.